# Is it possible to safely cancel a long running LogParser query from C#?

Tags: c#, logparser

I'm working with LogParser 2.2 in C# via COM interop and would like to be able to give long running queries a timeout.

e.g.

```
var ctx = new COMIISW3CInputContextClassClass();
var log = new LogQueryClassClass();
var rs = log.Execute(qry, ctx);
```

Is it possible to interrupt the `log.Execute` call if it takes too long?
I have tried `Thread.Abort()`, but it appears the ThreadAbortException waits until the Execute call finishes normally.

The code used to test `Thread.Abort()` is:

```
var ctx = new COMIISW3CInputContextClassClass();
var log = new LogQueryClassClass();
ILogRecordset rs = null;
var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        rs = log.Execute(qry, ctx);
    });
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();

t.Join(100);
t.Abort();

// this tests if the file lock is still held by log parser
Assert.Throws<IOException>(() =>
    File.OpenWrite(path));

t.join(10000);

// file is no longer locked
using (File.OpenWrite(path))
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
```

Comment: One possible workaround can be launching the above code in a separate AppDomain and killing the AppDomain if LogParser is Busy.

Comment: I'm worried that I'll find the AppDomain will behave the same way (wait until the COM call returns before cleaning up). I guess I need to test it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling execution with `Thread.Abort` is rarely safe. It is not safe in this case as there is no way to know the state of Log Parser's data structures. You could perform the query in a separate process which you communicate with using standard input/output, named pipes, WCF, or your favorite IPC technology. Then to cancel the query, use `Process.Kill` on that process.

NOTE: Don't know if Log Parser writes any temp files that this will leave behind. Other than that, Windows should clean up all state correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

See cancellation tokens: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997289.aspx